# Typescript: How to create 'lambda function call' for external method?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, lambda, typescript

#### The Problem

I am picking up Typescript and just learned that lambda functions are used to (*edit*) set the value of `this`. However, I'm not sure how to pass my view model's `this` into a function that calls another method that I have not defined. In my case, I'm trying to call a Knockout method.  See example:

#### Desired JavaScript:

```
var MyViewModel = (function () {
    function MyViewModel() {
        var _this = this;
        ...
        this.someMethod = function () {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.array1(), function (item) {
                while (item.array2().length < _this.array3.length) {
                    item.array2.push(12345);
                }
            });
        };
  ...
```

#### Actual JavaScript:

```
var MyViewModel = (function () {
    function MyViewModel() {
        var _this = this;
        ...
        this.someMethod = function () {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.array1(), function (item) {
                while (item.array2().length < this.array3.length) {
                    item.array2.push(12345);
                }
            });
        };
  ...
```

#### TypeScript:

```
method = () => {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.array1(), function(item){
        while(item.array2().length < this.array3().length){
            item.array2.push(0);
        }
    })
 }
```

#### One Solution...

One solution I've used was to manually set `this.array3().length` to `_this.array3.length()`, but that's pretty hacky and I do not like it.

How should I go about passing the right `this` into my inner function?

Comment: The phrase "preserve the scope of this" really should be "set the value of this", since *this* is always resolved in the current execution context.

Comment: Noted & updated my sentence.

Comment: Have you try to use `(item) => {` in place of  `function(item){` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another lambda to continue the chain of `this` :

```
method = () => {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.array1(), (item) => {  // NOTE here
        while(item.array2().length < this.array3().length){
            item.array2.push(0);
        }
    })
 }
```

Tips on `this` in TypeScript : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1